# Large lag between client and broker (possible flow control & credit behaviour)

Tags: activemq-artemis

We are testing our application suite that uses ActiveMQ Artemis 2.27.1 (cluster but of just 1) (Core protocol).

App A sends messages to a REQUEST Q then waits for a response on an equivalent REPLY Q (where correlation Id matches a unique value sent on the request)

App B is listening/consuming messages on the REQUEST Q to process them, and then immediately send a message on to the REPLY Q (where correlation id matches the unique value received on the request)
The original sending app App A receives the response message from the REPLY Q

This works fine, but when we run this under our 'peak' load (with varying message sizes from 1k to 5mb) we see some severe lags in sending messages from App A (we can see 10+ second delays between the client app saying it has sent the message and Artemis, with debug enabled, says it has received the message. Similarly we see large delays where App A receives the message on the REPLY Q vs when Artemis has processed that message.

In the Artemis debug logs we see lots of messages around:

```
DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerConsumerImpl {id=2, filter=FilterImpl sfilterString=JMSCorrelationID = 'ID:xys123etcetc', binding=LocalQueueBinding [address=REPLYQ1] queue=QueueImpl[name=REPLYQ1], postOfficeImpl=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=artemis-0], temp=false, filter=null, name=REPLYQ1, ClusterName=xxxxxx is busy for lack of credits. Current credits=0
```

And lots of

```
DEBUG org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.QueueImpl  QueueImpl[name=REPLYQ1], postOfficeImpl=PostOfficeImpl [server=ActiveMQServerImpl::name=artemis-0], temp=false :: All the consumers were busy, giving up now
```

So this suggests (?) Artemis is running out of flow control credits for consumers on Qs? We have tried setting consumerWindowSize=-1 (on the Address config) and also to a v. large positive value but it doesn't change the behaviour. We think this is possibly the cause of the huge lag we often see between client APP A consuming messages.

How is this flow control kicking in (and how can it be removed/reduced)? Note that we see lots of:

```
FlowControl::Received 1048576 credits, previous value = 0, currentValue = 1048576.
```

Where is this value of 1048576 coming from and can it be configured at Artemis or client?

We also see lots of these on our client APP B (when it is PRoducing/sending messages to REPLYQ1

```
org.apache.core.client : AMQ212054: Destination address=REPLYQ1 is blocked. If the system is configured to block make sure you consume messages on this configuration.
```

We are speculating that this may be a knock on effect of the above lack of credits?

Assistance would be greatly appreciated

All detail above - we have tried setting `consumerWindowSize`, `producerWindowSize`, `tcpSendBuffer`, `tcpReceiveBuffer` to try and alter credit / flow control behaviour.

Update - example of lag seen between client 'Send' and Artemis 'Receive'

(App Log)
2023-05-15 15:00:08.354 TRACE [App1] : sendRegularMessage::ClientMessageImpl[messageID=0, durable=true, address=REQUESTQ1.......

(App Log)
2023-05-15 15:00:08.354 TRACE [App1] : RemotingConnectionID=xxxxxxx Sending blocking PACKET (SessionSendMessage), channelID=11, responseAsync=true, requiresResponse=true......  address=REQUESTQ1.

(Artemis Log)
2023-05-15 15:00:22.317 DEBUG [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server.impl.ServerSessionImpl] Routing result for CoreMessage.......

UPDATE-
With regards to the major latency seen on the consumption of messages on a REPLYQ, where consumer listens for a JMS correlation Id, I am now less sure the issue is due to the lack of credits error (as we can see several examples of lag - e.g. 5 seconds - between a message arriving on the broker and being consumed, where there is no 'lack of credits' error). So we stepped through the example, and effectively saw this-
13:38:09 ServerSessionImpl create a consumer on queue (QUEUE1) JMSCorrelationID=xyz
13:38:10.0 ServerSessionImpl send(message=CoreMessage[messageID=123] JMSCorrelationID=abc (QUEUE1)
13:38:10.1 ServerSessionImpl send(message=CoreMessage[messageID=234] JMSCorrelationID=def
13:38:10.3 ServerSessionImpl send(message=CoreMessage[messageID=345] JMSCorrelationID=ghi
13:38:10.4 ServerSessionImpl send(message=CoreMessage[messageID=456] JMSCorrelationID=xyz
13:38:10.7 QueueImpl QUEUE1 doing deliver. messageReferences=0 with consumers=6
13:38:12.1 QueueImpl Checking to re-enable direct deliver on queue QUEUE1
13:38:12.1 QueueImpl setting direct deliverer to true on queue QUEUE1
13:38:12.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=123 JMSCorrelationID=abc .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:12.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=123 JMSCorrelationID=abc .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:12.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=123 JMSCorrelationID=abc .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:12.1 Routing result for messageID=123

13:38:13.0 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=234 JMSCorrelationID=def .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:13.0 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=234 JMSCorrelationID=def .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:13.0 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=234 JMSCorrelationID=def .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:13.1 Routing result for messageID=234

13:38:14.3 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=345 JMSCorrelationID=ghi .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:14.3 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=345 JMSCorrelationID=ghi .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:14.3 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=345 JMSCorrelationID=ghi .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:14.3 Routing result for messageID=345

13:38:15.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=456 JMSCorrelationID=xyz .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:15.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=456 JMSCorrelationID=xyz .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:15.1 ServerConsumerImpl messageID=456 JMSCorrelationID=xyz .... is a no match on consumer xxx JMSCorrelationId ...
13:38:15.1 Routing result for messageID=456

So as per above, a 5 second gap between the message received in Artemis, checking for consumer matches on other messages, then checking for consumer match on the message in question and finding a match

Comment: Where exactly "on the Address config" are you configuring `consumerWindowSize`?

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that as the reply queue grows it naturally incurs a greater and greater performance penalty due to the consumer's use of a selector to get the message it wants. The use of a selector requires scanning the queue to find a match. The deeper the queue the longer this scanning can take. One way to mitigate this issue is by using a temporary queue for the reply and setting this on the message using [`setJMSReplyTo`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/jms/Message.html#setJMSReplyTo-javax.jms.Destination-). This would eliminate the need to use a correlation ID.

Comment: Thanks @Justin. Consumer window size set using an <address-settings-match="#"> and within there we set <default-consumer-window-size>-1</default-consumer-window-size> (we also tried a large value in there too). So far, we simply can't work out a) how to prevent this 'credit' check we see in the logs (in particular to prevent the 'all the consumers are busy giving up now' which sounds like it could be a symptom of continual 'is busy due to lack of credits') and b) why we see such large gaps between client code sending messages and Artemis receiving (and only under load)

Comment: Try setting `consumerWindowSize=-1` on the client's connection URL (e.g. `tcp://host:61616?consumerWindowSize=-1`).

Comment: Hi @JustinBertram. I have tried this and we still see lots of messages - is busy for lack of credits. Current credits=0

Comment: @JustinBertram I can see the part of the code that throws these lack of credit messages - see links. But I still can't work out what parameter/property is effecting it......https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/artemis-server/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/core/server/impl/ServerConsumerImpl.java

Comment: Have edited the main question with an update on the lag seen on consumer side when consuming messages with JMS Correlation Id. I know you said there was performance penalties for doing message selection on JMSCorrelationid, but would we expect 5 seconds (sometimes more) when there only seem to be ~5 messages and 5 consumers?

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Artemis, you have allocated number of consumers on the jboss side on the application.
you need to define it on the jboss side and on the application side ...
as you have here 3 partners:
the Artemis
the JBoss
the app that running on the jboss .
you need to define a data source to connect to AMQ , there you need to define enough connections- "max-pool-size" and "thread-pool-max-size" , this way you will have enough workers to do it ...